# How can we install the root package through stock recovery in android, even though it is not signed

Tags: installation, recovery-mode

I've read that for some signature verification and signing reasons in android, The stock recovery doesn't allow us to install a custom rom directly using "Update from SD Card". And so we need to have a custom recovery installed so that no signature problems occur.

My question is that while rooting and installing a custom recovery we install a "update.zip package" from our stock recovery mode. So doesn't any signature verification occur over there?

How does the stock recovery allow installation of unsigned root and custom recovery packages but doesn't allow installation of custom rom directly?

Comment: I think some devices can root by installing a forged update.zip. You imply all devices can be rooted like this but that's not true.

Comment: @jiggunjer  Suppose I need to root my phone, in order to do that I have a root.zip package(unsigned) which won't get flashed by my stock recovery and so I'll have to now add a custom recovery so that I can flash that root.zip file. Now how do I install a custom recovery because mostly all methods on the internet uses a application "Rom Manager" that needs root privileges. So, isn't this a deadlock now . I want to flash root file but to do that I need custom recovery and to get custom recovery I need root. *DEADLOCK*.

Comment: Not a deadlock, most people use a PC flashing program (odin/fastboot/SP-flashtool) that will install a new recovery over USB. Another option sometimes is to root with a one-click app like kingroot/framaroot, then use some Rom Manager or whatever.

Comment: And also this means that if my phone is brand new, doesn't have any custom recovery and is not rooted then I have to have use PC atleast once to either root it or install custom recovery into it.

Comment: Depends on the model. Some phones *can* root using update.zip on the stock recovery (e.g. samsung n7000).

Comment: For that the update.zip needs to be signed properly and so I guess it is a matter of the zip file and not phone(here Samsung n7000) . Am I correct ?

Comment: Yea I think that's right.